# How to check if the PIN has a certain value

Tags: gsm, modem, at-command

I'm developing on a mobile gsm platform and I need to know the PIN in order to change it. Is there a way to verify if the [PIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_identification_number) has a certain value?

I'm looking for the solution that makes use of [AT commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set) since this is the only way to control the gsm modem.

I need this to prevent the use of the SIM card for data transfer, calls etc in personal phones or other devices.

Is there a simple way to find out what the PIN is (highly unlikely) or to check if the PIN is the one from a list of expected values?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot extract the pin with the standard command set, `AT+CPIN=XXXX` will respond with `OK` if `XXXX` is the correct pin, otherwise it will generate a CME error - however submitting 3 incorrect attempts can cause the SIM to lock until the PUK code is entered.

If you know the PUK however, you could always change the pin to a known value without needing the original PIN (`AT+CPIN` again).

Comment: Agree, but if I don't need to enter PIN (AT+CPIN? says +CPIN: READY) it there a way to check what is the value of the PIN ? (In my application I have only 2 options: a default value and a value from a configuration file)

Comment: I don't think you can read the pin via any conventional method

Comment: Yes, I agree but I just need to check if it has a certain value, even if that pin is not required. I would probably need to look further into the device's manual. Thanks